# Compiler change in Java 7

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, java-7

In Java 6 I was able to use:

```
public static <T, UK extends T, US extends T> T getCountrySpecificComponent(UK uk, US us) {
    Country country = CountryContext.getCountry();
    if (country == Country.US) {
        return us;
    } else if (country == Country.UK) {
        return uk;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unhandled country returned: "+country);
    }
}
```

With these repositories:

```
public interface Repository{
   List<User> findAll();
}

public interface RepositoryUS extends Repository{}

public interface RepositoryUK extends Repository{}
```

When using these:

```
RepositoryUK uk = ...
RepositoryUS us = ...
```

This line compiles in in Java6 but fails in Java7 (error cannot find symbol - as the compiler looks for findAll() on class Object)

```
List<User> users = getCountrySpecificComponent(uk, us).findAll();
```

This compiles in Java 7

```
List<User> users = ((Repository)getCountrySpecificComponent(uk, us)).findAll();
```

I know this is a rather uncommon use case but is there a reason for this change? Or a way to tell the compiler to be a little "smarter"?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `T` type?  Could you eliminate that generic parameter and have `UK` and `US` extend `Repository`?  I think that's the root of the problem - the compiler can't know that everything you pass to `getCountrySpecificComponent()` is a `Repository` unless you tell it so.

Comment: Good question! I want to use it for all kinds of repositories, services and other stuff that is Country specific. I'm just trying to make it more generic/useable.

Comment: I don't see how this could have compiled even in Java 6 unless some dangerous assumption was made...  Why should `T` be `Repository`, when it can just as easily be `Object` in the case given?

Comment: I don't know and I guess it was a dangerous assumption, but it worked for us. We actually never had problems with it so I was happy with less code.

Comment: I agree that was a dangerous assumption.  Since you want this method to work for more than just `Repository` objects, you probably want another base interface.  See my answer below.

Comment: Since I have some Scala code in the project I just converted it to scala and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `T` should be bounded to extend `Repository`. This way the compiler knows that `getCountrySpecificComponent` returns some repository.

**EDIT:**

It should also be ok to write: `public static <T extends Repository> T getCountrySpecificComponent(T uk, T us)`

Answer (score 0):

Then I agree it was a mistake for the old compiler to accept that.  I think you want something like this:

```
public interface UserFindingComponent{
   List<User> findAll(); 
}

public interface Repository extends UserFindingComponent{ }

public interface RepositoryUS extends Repository{}

public interface RepositoryUK extends Repository{}
```

...

```
public static <T extends UserFindingComponent, UK extends T, US extends T> T getCountrySpecificComponent(UK uk, US us) {
    Country country = CountryContext.getCountry();
    if (country == Country.US) {
        return us;
    } else if (country == Country.UK) {
        return uk;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unhandled country returned: "+country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the compiler was unable to infer the type parameters, which probably should have been the case in Java 6 as well. You can tell the compiler what the generic types are however, using the syntax below:

```
import java.util.List;

class User {
}

interface Repository {
  List<User> findAll();
}

interface RepositoryUS extends Repository {
}

interface RepositoryUK extends Repository {
}

class Test {
  public static <T, UK extends T, US extends T> T getCountrySpecificComponent(UK uk, US us) {
    Country country = CountryContext.getCountry();
    if (country == Country.US) {
      return us;
    } else if (country == Country.UK) {
      return uk;
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Unhandled country returned: " + country);
    }
    return us;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    RepositoryUK uk = null;
    RepositoryUS us = null;
    List<User> users = Test.<Repository, RepositoryUK, RepositoryUS>getCountrySpecificComponent(uk, us).findAll(); 
  }
}
```